# How to resample a Pandas multi-index data frame via methods depending on the column name

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Here is a Pandas v0.14.0 data frame with multi-index columns.

```
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
>
> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2001', periods=6, freq='H')
> mi = [(dt, i) for dt in rng for i in range(2)]
> f = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(mi), 2), 
> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mi, names=['time', 'extra']),
  columns =['A', 'B']) 
> g = f.unstack('extra') 
> g

                            A                   B          
extra                       0         1         0         1
time                                                       
2001-01-01 00:00:00 -0.169742  0.390842 -0.017884  1.043376
2001-01-01 01:00:00 -0.184442 -0.102512 -0.013702  0.675290
2001-01-01 02:00:00  0.244708 -0.360740  1.059269 -0.330537
2001-01-01 03:00:00 -2.275161 -1.782581  0.754368 -0.157851
2001-01-01 04:00:00 -0.554282  0.310691  0.917221 -0.114459
2001-01-01 05:00:00  0.599133  0.904824  1.858538  1.319041
```

I can resample `g` successfully using one method across all columns, e.g. by `g.resample('6H', how=np.sum)`.  How can i resample `g` with different methods for each column, e.g. by summing the 'A' columns and averaging the 'B' columns?

I tried the following, which works for non-multi-index columns, but got an error.

```
> g.resample('6H', how={'A': np.sum, 'B': np.mean})

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-b1a72fd62178> in <module>()
      4 g = f.unstack('extra')
      5 print(g)
----> 6 g.resample('6H', how={'A': np.sum, 'B': np.mean})

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
   2834                               fill_method=fill_method, convention=convention,
   2835                               limit=limit, base=base)
-> 2836         return sampler.resample(self).__finalize__(self)
   2837 
   2838     def first(self, offset):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py in resample(self, obj)
     81 
     82         if isinstance(ax, DatetimeIndex):
---> 83             rs = self._resample_timestamps()
     84         elif isinstance(ax, PeriodIndex):
     85             offset = to_offset(self.freq)

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py in _resample_timestamps(self)
    252                 # downsample
    253                 grouped = obj.groupby(grouper, axis=self.axis)
--> 254                 result = grouped.aggregate(self._agg_method)
    255             else:
    256                 # upsampling shortcut

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   2402                     colg = SeriesGroupBy(obj[col], selection=col,
   2403                                          grouper=self.grouper)
-> 2404                     result[col] = colg.aggregate(agg_how)
   2405                     keys.append(col)
   2406 

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
   2078             cyfunc = _intercept_cython(func_or_funcs)
   2079             if cyfunc and not args and not kwargs:
-> 2080                 return getattr(self, cyfunc)()
   2081 
   2082             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in mean(self)
    668             self._set_selection_from_grouper()
    669             f = lambda x: x.mean(axis=self.axis)
--> 670             return self._python_agg_general(f)
    671 
    672     def median(self):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   1012         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate output dict
   1013         output = {}
-> 1014         for name, obj in self._iterate_slices():
   1015             try:
   1016                 result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _iterate_slices(self)
    650 
    651     def _iterate_slices(self):
--> 652         yield self.name, self._selected_obj
    653 
    654     def transform(self, func, *args, **kwargs):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:37563)()

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _selected_obj(self)
    461             return self.obj
    462         else:
--> 463             return self.obj[self._selection]
    464 
    465     def _set_selection_from_grouper(self):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1682             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1683         else:
-> 1684             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1685 
   1686     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1689         # get column
   1690         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1691             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1692 
   1693         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionaility

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1050         res = cache.get(item)
   1051         if res is None:
-> 1052             values = self._data.get(item)
   1053             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1054             cache[item] = res

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item)
   2535 
   2536             if not isnull(item):
-> 2537                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   2538             else:
   2539                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in get_loc(self, key)
   1154         loc : int if unique index, possibly slice or mask if not
   1155         """
-> 1156         return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
   1157 
   1158     def get_value(self, series, key):

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3650)()

/Users/araichev/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/index.so in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3577)()

KeyError: 'B'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with f, you can use a groupby with a TimeGrouper to do the resample "manually":

```
In [11]: grp = f.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('6H', level=0))

In [12]: grp['A'].sum()
Out[12]:
0
2001-01-01   -1.805954
Freq: 6H, Name: A, dtype: float64

In [13]: grp['B'].mean()
Out[13]:
0
2001-01-01   -0.461053
Freq: 6H, Name: B, dtype: float64
```

If you want to separate based on the extra add that to the groupby*:

```
In [21]: grp2 = f.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('6H', level=0),
                             f.index.get_level_values('extra')])

In [22]: grp2['A'].sum()
Out[22]:
0           extra
2001-01-01  0        2.030321
            1       -3.836275
Name: A, dtype: float64

In [23]: grp2['B'].mean()
Out[23]:
0           extra
2001-01-01  0       -0.554839
            1       -0.367267
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

**Note: groupby with a column and a TimeGrouper won't work in versions prior to 0.14.*

To get from g to f you can reshape with stack:

```
In [31]: f2 = g.stack(level=1)  # Note: use stack to get f from g
```

and back from the results above to a similar format:

```
In [32]: pd.DataFrame({'A': grp['A'].sum(), 'B': grp['B'].mean()})
Out[32]:
                         A         B
0          extra
2001-01-01 0     -2.762064 -0.269427
           1     -2.006839 -0.026213

In [33]: _.unstack(level=1)
Out[33]:
                   A                   B
extra              0         1         0         1
0
2001-01-01 -2.762064 -2.006839 -0.269427 -0.026213
```

---

Another approach, which might be "simpler", in that you actually do the resample, is to make the dict from the columns:

```
In [41]: dict(zip(g.columns,
                  map({'A': 'sum', 'B': 'mean'}.get,
                      [x[0] for x in g.columns])))
Out[41]: {('A', 0): 'sum', ('A', 1): 'sum', ('B', 0): 'mean', ('B', 1): 'mean'}

In [42]: g.resample('6H', _)
Out[42]:
                   A         B         A         B
                   1         0         0         1
time
2001-01-01 -3.836275 -0.554839  2.030321 -0.367267
```

Comment: OK. How do i put ``grp2['A']`` and ``grp2['B']`` back together into one data frame with the same structure as ``g``?

Comment: @araichev Something like this: `pd.DataFrame([grp['A'].sum(), grp['B'].mean()]).T` ?

Comment: Hmm, that's almost the same structure as ``f`` (it's missing the 'time' label), but not ``g``.  The following seems to work.  ``ff = g.stack('extra'); grp2 = ff.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('3H', level=0), ff.index.get_level_values('extra')]); h = pd.concat([grp2['A'].sum(), grp2['B'].mean()], axis=1, keys=ff.columns); hh = h.unstack('extra'); hh.index.name = g.index.name``  Fyew.  I wish there were a more elegant solution.

Comment: Before accepting this answer, i'll wait for a day to see if someone submits a simpler solution.

Comment: @araichev sheesh, I think you can do it a little better (my original construction wasn't that good, dict construction gets you there in one go). I also added alternative approach.

Comment: @Andy_Hayden, your dictionary solution is nice and natural, because it's a direct extension of the non-hierarchical column case. I see now why my original resampling attempt failed: i wasn't specifying the column names correctly.

Comment: Oh, one last thing. I noticed that the names of the hierarchical index disappear after resampling: 'extra' goes away.  Is this a bug?

Comment: @araichev I think it could be, worth filing an issue on github :)